# как сделать регулярное выражение, которое находит первые 6 символов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Необходимо создать регулярное выражение, которое должно найти первые 6 символов в строке, если они являются числами. Как это сделать в коде?

Comment: [`^\d{6}`](https://regexr.com/57hrr)

Comment: Эммм... `^\d{6}`?

Comment: Ну вот, пока я придумывал, как раздуть ответ с 6 символов до 30, его уже дважды написали в комментарии...

Comment: @Qwertiy *как раздуть ответ с 6 символов до 30* Да хоть до 1+6*(10+2)=73...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто взять и найти - куда уж проще??

```
^\d{6}
```

Comment: работает. спасибо